# Why am I getting 404 error while calling nordstrom API?

Tags: python, api, python-requests

I am working on a project, where I need to fetch data from the website https://shop.nordstrom.com/ . So I have found the API Path using the browsers developer tools and I am getting the desired data using the code.

```
import requests

headers = {
    "User-Agent": "Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Ubuntu; Linux x86_64; rv:72.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/72.0",
    "X-y8S6k3DB-f": "A5fsimxzAQAAXThaRLorrh5k5lL_p8mJQXwo8DU-HOpGQ7_0SP_rtn5pyR0dAWrXywecuNHLwH8AADQwAAAAAA==",
    "X-y8S6k3DB-b": "7wpway",
    "X-y8S6k3DB-c": "AAAvhmxzAQAAs3x6cnUjncp33yutLbK3XL0Tv0ydzK8d0wXcy1u5sFU5Wu84",
    "X-y8S6k3DB-d": "AAaihIjBDKGNgUGASZAQhISy1WJbubBVOVrvOCPT0RQSNP1UANWIvM0jQIBnE0s-osGGqeo",
    "X-y8S6k3DB-z": "q",
    "X-y8S6k3DB-a": "hWnx1mfhHxxwaM5mNCdxuw6toV=gG4lMyThmOls6UU6LmSDIZM3mLhXVIM73gX70D4eVMB0O2MZcpiuSYn7b=A68qp06FsXYlEVM7rQ9GllZpyLQPeFsjhkT7zPlPbo7d=5nWBVaCMkaTRkqB_XHtgyUwfYCrCh9lEdnPffx1GOS841ZzA79ymTrgHuxr0e2HbB8eOwRY3tZPmYedhkpSx3iumWiZGc6tWizhw8gPbRDNnYtdhJjqque4=ALzEcWOuPt4JP98DbaJm85nSBxu9iqHn2I6AHBy9SUGRnEOoo5XkUhxyF3OTuhqS42_kaDiNgRFHp1P7LQ6C9B5bOOpFSK6EawpPM8qIcLWLim_wYlSaRvN99qh9onyp8407AyIKIfK2PDnNenJwrBWH9e6TMO_914IqWeh8rwmbRbSLEesS6Qs8XOi2umo0BIhCD4HyqWeg9uvZGxah=blmwaYOcp0HcGGStKqwKxz7FfJW7hj2NC5J4_fSCyZOI30xpJ6V5lO1BL1c2j=PWJjejFBShzyaRUa25ymf7KKjaEYpkUu3k2NwUns0mvEUmFCvl5Qy7ZsTQqstKqdbVBsqKYsMtnbXUvlcu1itWAspbJ36gwz7VW_6u5QZDEmN47VPGyuVQDhX=gCnUmSODTOlq5tLRYEiAXjhliKvqrKQ14Fjbx8IYU5udYTZxypGIpVpO=Qlelg1tqpHoXv9=c_HgtyUbth5VsyUxOH3GAzqLRwRyCzUP31S9fNu30_g99G3I5ZXCQIiqUD4LqKSxVLHgQs6tPOaDGntMDc82mugFFiNVZ=b5LkX=aqyTygR3YRsBfvUwHWvokVXY9Qh8WrNa5yI8zyTSwcZ9R8rGG738bB0sI_9WEnvoCq4U7EN2mPEKHgLOMPZK9N9EVHjoa=RAbl8=y5V3QdJ2HigV09OFagvU=XpjLBZeQ5EvEl=AO8VJhXe_KoCgXf6USYRQi8QoBmOtdfU0Y_gk7Lfz5GpLTHVWWgPi0_9MLFSdNrFwGCRqxYCymUyl707I7lEaojbmiUJr6s_liVdY4SZJF6OjwuDe28b_xEdpMLBg54RA3DKM4a72piRdPy6fg71a5X=ba=ago_ePkoPdgfRSFDrFBRiKs9ZadT13EMaGCdAB4uEHKNhBK12Alm6NqP5aX9uAKb7gTMceSXAtJc4GcYaooJtOX9TyO01_gOLgd3_0FlX_W193zR1bPUpVbzDiVKAELRnbvZxlbcjuwbZ3FYGvQqFPmGjUWFRpi5eSjuq6LmcYtxL_DnjKICOt=_2cyIc_lOcdGEJMk1z6J6okIXHumxuOnUhKWzgaRIffSbTRXnqZan9QEE_W859tCNItHbWzePR09kzJGY=m7AGW=TJenI3zeExwlNfMW2ug53uEXAgypbK8e9OocXZ4syuZqsoTjaDmUMxLTYJ_2kKoDyj4lMcTBQUz4KLr5DfiS47_H3N8toyH7pqU0koc4lJ=vk9ylZb8OInv2OdGi4INe4SAYwjxH36=pU14pXzurqSP=kJ8RWuDUIF72=8IHWksYIG1aAm643X5Q60ftIi2AVTAXMHObosiMOwxaBCP4CRmGJ6PfiPSWVjjIiTQkiqTrAVBxkGeWLcAQsFbsVjJL8U39y9PEwF5ORjC94LFSutpR=0pA2sv5OUXsUuxMWXYwwehM1ZamxNtj=uD3CGjY2ysk8DsIJNP17vWscKhQoW8Rp0oURjGCrVmlaPw16J8VWSKAMEc3qVsVLgE69WLL9WJ3bTueE=NrcAUEzrdp=wZYgeiKrxfiroR7HS3fFd4nRBnLyEXIUG_c2kTHq97jyXjBM2olse2lJBkWOLoTJMlp4C1kcVWcN7jiAIFlJypGsVSx3FMRJIZRkrWVHgUzsN2ekq5xLskTWdkbyOPCsWOkJSj6EOXPiyYrPktaLe5kNH0ICHVzQkp5ljROnTI0hBrvx42afatScsRrPBjvJsSuOnxC3a5L1RQDnjmZlJ6SIfsM_pM2uloFbnJg_m9ovzRfo15T5IenhIjT5GE9cNsV=AfVFidYgPuGL8B5JwpLFi=3H=9ARd45XeI=yYbVUWMHN=_4mGNrxXMi0czV1a827xVV8rLyRN1Vf5xK=CQCXhkyKwqFkzvbilKlZlCN06ZA8q=vKRsWcLm1ucFUiHOlqYBwiiAdrttMTYfKqOOcX2aNVLBXTURGDoOTos0zyQggdpqXfEkSQ9cBzYGRU90evbTnXQfSa3GUzL4nccJezebuqU1hM0_SMId6032oQKKhkXVNF_l0Xb=W7lqiqf7ULPpNQpqS3HFLKPspVKmVeCu=SD_ONmkW_zQKcWAxos34NFwZz5m7tBEpnMTqDG3MFz8TIOXD2RGWmc24BVT0CzKn9vfV9BzfyD4g4ZLMWP_v=sOT9K22yCTiXZvFfvc4ylUZ0QJyM4Zhu=WohaPphcbPoaYapgwAElO3hhLqF753FfCOa4GfWcyrLSPmHh_nf=U770FIwsXvuLrN5paVbJN2So5COAHIrZ4piz=AIhPyLFWQbiLmm3zhv2n8gtJX0Ptdmu3o6JJKBCm5GYfbuLs5NAwOjqWMI9YZkv7w9bks=xgs=at75uXkAZM8x72V05UD8MdCB5Fyc4CObs73hzSnh8spn_6lbtL0iD0TmB_JdC6gUwX88yMi7AjjrruYGL4walACdtQ1zvH2gH3ECfD7NEOOiWYcGPtZ6tmVFfqXfkqhOzm_IWDYVhOWD7BEq8WP4FIPlsnO5rTZXI3_NL6DPlUpwZsfS0WKIYAj_C8HcY=Q61Vznk6DVc6I2SVcDwuubIC=U8vTebJTV5MdyXRHClgrwdtG4eDQ5qqmnixL=nRRGhYNbHqTxFDrBv1rNwFdNoeB1W0h4IPylT2QHuzTs5RMn96K0_jpDM38pEAq4JVGjwhXzQ0N000b5l=pErM1cRDItVGOINDe0aqRSExIzt8zYlBpvhJACICzMJOxO4xTOOsePef5nz315vUrnWoNbkm1JfDXe1=3Q8Ci7pJbuUgCNjY1jxERY7bKy1tOoqpUKRPUe8xZ_Sf9mDSO4KcHZ1ROKrzR2m0DDrwjB8nbq=R39tBz2kUGhAnoG1wTBqVtxSN0Rp0f6dHqO_oXoti6S80iVJem_TGloxPK7Z2iRGo6ycoIOrgSWAU4AzRLsu62RkCmxoSLQhq4fOpRoUm9PJApPy6C4ZF=vnt62ZqEp85QFGBcFMjSn6ODhPoKlKe5LQxXlh0y8BX=hULgHtqavd_htYEOnnYWMce6hM8lh=grWjyMV0mwn_HNldcVlgp8p=0vdFOf4Z9Qen6Q7k8=M8qwj5_c=ZYm0sPllTEk0_UjtY=CczT5b8Sr5Vq5dfyDLp9AP_lxPu0rSx2KtIb3px4tSZt29al45CiWUC1tuP3GdVyj2rVUiG4yyu38Q_jZJTYGrLBDMpoWWjR16yAPyfsiB0wTdo0==sbysPxFld=gQOKZR7Yc5yCv_P4lZ4XANCSJhAZPcLfPizzYS66Bh3FHtpUdS_RHlYfzALAiLtMNwED9Scz0JIm9VBNocHxOjSZjQCK5cfcnwDIZvycA0GAGOPdNZD4o8a2IqNFBRzPOldNcGia4av2Sq2gCbGXj8VfKgIbcrVQGr1th0uyNo_x75kKeg8pTgHCJEerQwGRg4vgP_XFJrEaphWk3F4nH=7DONoMWEUDs8JsxVbwXfEO7po33_XWZx_B4_mhqeYmXqq69aE9bjTWVye8mapLCjdz_qr_lbkMYFJptrtbbMniDV30VSMB9LonUBXxcm=WYl2QeVzXlWpRrjfAA4KJBRDTCWhPLKQSwuzRB4xhTvXDSk2jXvl_vM4os8FldJA70ezIEEYwGyF7ZKMxyqwZ1Rg9joSt1yEo6lUwOgNha3G2Rwr8m4yN46KSmnMpuCPtHz2zF",
}

data = requests.get('https://www.nordstrom.com/api/search/query/t%20shirt/?top=72&origin=keywordsearch&sort=CustomerRating&offset=0', headers=headers)

print(data.json())
```

I copied the headers from the developer tools.

This is working fine. But the problem is after about 2-3 days, it starts to give `404 error`. I am not sure why am I getting the error ?

Comment: Some of those `X-` headers are probably some sort of token that expires after some time

Comment: Is there any way, I can update them ? (preferably automated )

Comment: If there is not public documentation for this API, chances are that you are not *intended* to be able to make it work at all.